# How does one programmatically mix multiple audio tracks into one track?

Tags: merge, audio, audacity

What is the algorithm used by Audacity (or any other audio editing program) to mix separate sound tracks?

ie. what is the process of merging the tracks to a single one when the "Mix and Render" command is used.

Answer (score 1):

you just add the signals.

```
// fill the destination (output) with the sum of signals: input1, input2, input3
for (size_t idx(0); idx < samplesToWrite; ++idx) {
    output[idx] = input1[idx] + input2[idx] + input3[idx];
}
```

to apply volume or panning to a signal, use multiplication.

```
// to halve the amplitude of an audio signal:
const double halfVolume = 0.5;
for (size_t idx(0); idx < samplesToWrite; ++idx) {
    signal[idx] *= halfVolume;
}
```

Comment: You normally need some scaling too - just adding tracks without scaling will typically result in clipping.

Comment: @Paul R thanks. it's fairly common to scale, particularly with int formats. also, it depends on the context... but that depends entirely on the sample format used, and what the user should expect from the result. if the destination is float, then the risk does not exist in a practical uses (for the destination sample data representation). if it were a bounce in place implementation to file with integer sample data, then i think it's better to tell the user the bounce has clipped. the OP didn't specify a particular sample format, but i assumed DerNalia was familiar with limits and conversions.